# How to display console output in Counter Strike: Source?

Tags: counter-strike-source

Is it possible to display console output somewhere at the top of the screen, for example? I use console `echo` command sometimes and it display something to console. But to see what was displayed I have to open console <kbd>~</kbd> and then close it. But I want to see what was echoed immediately. I want to achieve something like on the screen shot below:

[image]

Red text says:
**This is the console output. Everything in console I want to see here. How can I accomplish that?**

Answer (score 1):

In console, or preferably in an autoexec.cfg, set:

```
developer 1
```

Comment: I've already tried. I get 
`Can't use cheat cvar developer in multiplayer, unless the server has sv_cheats set to 1.` I want to use this feature in multiplayer.  And `sv_cheats` is `0` on the servers.

Comment: It's not considered a cheat in 1.6 or GO... interesting.